# How to use an Integration User with a REST site: documentation request

Tags: rest, guest-user

My app is a Lightning native Twilio integration that uses a REST site to receive data from Twilio.

I would like to run flows that are triggered by data created by these incoming http POSTs. However, even when I run the flows in System context, they retain the Guest Site User context that prevents using the Slack actions in flows (the Slack permission set can't be assigned to Guest Site User). I've had similar issues where in Guest Site User context, I can't access credentials that are stored in Custom Settings.

I'm reading about the Integration User and that seems like it might be a possible solution, but I can't find any explanation to help me understand how to use it in connection to my incoming data from the REST site. I'd appreciate pointers to documentation on this. Thanks.

Comment: Is Twilio capable of using an authenticated user, or are webhooks all you get?

Comment: Twilio uses Webhooks only.